# Duplicate column (from right table) with values before nullified during left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I want the original nulled out values inside the matched left join result grid.

`TABLE A` LEFT JOIN `TABLE B`

I need to Duplicate a column (from TABLE B) with values before being nullified during left join.h

Basically I am comparing an answersheet with a expectedanswer sheet. 
So I left join answsheet to keysheet.
I used

```
case when `key` is null then 'not correct' ELSE 'correct' END  AS `result`
```

to create a column as result.

But I also want to tell the user that this was the expected answer.

Comment: what condition you are using for join. I think you can use normal join on question id then in case statement you can match ans.

Comment: on `tablea`.`id`=`tableb`.`id` and `tablea`.`ans`=`tableb`.`key`;

Comment: you can use only tablea.id = tableb.id in on for join and in case statement you can use case when tabea.ans = tableb.key then 'correct' else 'not correct' end as 'result'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the answers in the case, not the join condition:

```
select  s.user
,       'Your answer = ' + s.submitted_answer
,       'Right answer = ' + q.expected_answer 
,       case 
        when s.submitted_answer = q.expected_answer then 'correct'
        else 'incorrect'
        end
from    submission s
join    question q
on      s.question_id = q.id
```

Comment: . . No offense to you, but I'm surprised that a query that is syntactically incorrect for MySQL would be chosen as the correct answer by the OP.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I guess for MySQL you need `concat('Your answer = ', s.submitted_answer)`